# How do I clear out an array's contents and replace with new contents of nested collection?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I have a Project model that has a nested collection of ProjectSlides. The project slides are images that I would like (to iterate over) to show which are specific to the particular project that was clicked on.

I can click on the project name in the project list and it shows the images, iterating through each one properly. If I click on another project name, I expect the array holding the first project's images (project slides) to clear out and be replaced with the project slide images of the new project I clicked on. However, the images belonging to the project slides of the first project do clear out, and the second project's project slide images are appended to the array.

## Question

How do I get the array to clear out its contents when I click on another project and have the array populate with the new project's project slide images?

## In my projects controller I have the following code:

Displays the list of projects:

```
showProjectList: (projects) ->
  projectListView = @getProjectListView projects
  Demo.AboutApp.Show.on "project-name:link:clicked", (project) =>
    console.log project
    @showProject project # passes project model that was clicked on from another view

  @projectsLayout.projectListRegion.show projectListView
```

Get specific  Project that was clicked on:

```
showProject: (project) ->
  console.log project
  console.log project.get('project_slides')

  newProjectView = @getProjectDetailsView project
  @projectsLayout.projectDetailsRegion.show newProjectView
  console.log slides
  # When I click on another project name, how can I check to see if the array exists? 
  # If the array exists, then set its length to 0 (to empty the previous project's nested collection), 
  # and then add the nested collection project slides of the other project project I clicked on? 
  # Is there some way to scope an array based on an event? That event would create the array, if one doesn't exist, 
  # or if it does exist, empty its contents and replace? I'm so lost.
  project_slides = project.get('project_slides')  # shows project_slides
  slides = (slide for slide in project_slides) # creates the slides array, placing each member of the project slides nested collection in the array. 
  console.log "slides: #{slides}"
  i = 0
  len = slides.length

  callback = ->
    slide = slides[i] # gets the current iteration of the slides array
    slideView = Demo.ProjectsApp.Show.Controller.getSlidesView slide # creates the view
    Demo.ProjectsApp.Show.Controller.projectsLayout.projectSlidesRegion.show slideView # appends the view to the projectsSlideRegion         
    console.log slide
    i++
    i = 0 if i >= len
    return

  setInterval callback, 5000

  slideView = @getSlidesView slides
  @projectsLayout.projectSlidesRegion.show slideView
```

## View Code:

```
class Show.ProjectName extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
  template: JST["backbone/apps/projects/templates/_project_name_on_project_list"]
  tagName: "li"

  events:
    "click a.project-link" : -> 
      Demo.AboutApp.Show.trigger "project-name:link:clicked", @model

  triggers:
    "click .project-link" : "project:link:clicked" 

 class Show.ProjectSlideList extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
   template: JST["backbone/apps/projects/templates/_project_slide"]
   tagName: "li"
   itemViewContainer: "project-slides"
   initialize: ->
     console.log "ProjectSlideList View initialized"
     console.log this

   modelEvents:
     "add" : "render"
     "change" : "render"
```

## Model & Collection:

```
class Entities.Project extends Backbone.Model
  url: -> Routes.project_path(id)

class Entities.ProjectsCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  model: Entities.Project
  url: -> Routes.projects_path()
```

## 5/22/13 Final code in controller:

```
showProjectList: (projects) ->
  projectListView = @getProjectListView projects
  Demo.AboutApp.Show.on "project-name:link:clicked", (project) =>
    clearInterval @timer # <-- this is important; gets rid of previous project
    @showProject project

  @projectsLayout.projectListRegion.show projectListView

  # Project id

showProject: (project) ->
  console.log project
  project_slides = project.get('project_slides')  
  newProjectView = @getProjectDetailsView project
  @projectsLayout.projectDetailsRegion.show newProjectView
  slideIndex = -1
  slides_length = project_slides.length

  getNextSlide = ->
    console.log project
    console.log project_slides
    slideIndex++
    slide = project_slides[slideIndex]
    slideIndex = 0 if slideIndex >= slides_length
    console.log slide
    slideView = Demo.ProjectsApp.Show.Controller.getSlidesView slide
    Demo.ProjectsApp.Show.Controller.projectsLayout.projectSlidesRegion.show slideView
    return

  @timer = setInterval getNextSlide, 5000
```

I am using Rails on the backend and the rabl gem. This allows me to pass project_slides as a child collection to the parent project. In other words, project_slides is already an array of project_slide objects. I simply needed to iterate over them at an interval.

```
Project {cid: "c32", attributes: Object, collection: ProjectsCollection, _changing: false, attributes: Object}
  detail: "first project details"
  id: 1
  logo: "project-icon.png"
  name: "First Project Name"
  problem: "The First Project's Problem Description"
  project_slides: Array[4]
    0: Object
      avatar: "first_image.png"
      caption: "first image's caption"
      id: 1
      project_id: 1
     __proto__: Object
    1: Object
    2: Object
    3: Object
      length: 4
  cid: "c32"
  collection: ProjectsCollection
  id: 1
```

When I click on a new project, marionette js takes care of zombies and populates the correct data. No need to create another slides collection when one was being passed already. Man, I couldn't see the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Rails on the backend and the rabl gem. This facilitates passing project_slides as a child collection to the parent project as json. In other words, project_slides is already an array of project_slide objects. I simply needed to iterate over them at an interval. When I click on a new project, marionette js takes care of zombies and populates the correct data. No need to create another slides collection when one was being passed already. Man, I couldn't see the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look into storing your slides within a collection. Then, all you'd have to do is

```
slides.reset(project_slides)
```

Using a collection is especially useful in Marionette, since a collectionView will rerender itself when the collection triggers the "reset" event.

If you want to learn more about using collection views, take a look at pages 21-31 in http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf (full disclosure: I'm the author)

Comment: Hi @David thank you so much for your reply. I placed the
          slides.reset(project_slides) 

but I get an error:
    Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'reset'

Comment: or would the slides.reset(project_slides) go in the initialize method of the Show.ProjectSlideList? Thank you for your help!

Comment: It seems you haven't changed your code and are trying to reset an array, which isn't possible. You need to have your `slides` be a collection (e.g. `var slides = new SlideCollection()`). Of course, you'll need to have defined `SlideCollection` as extending `Backbone.Collection`. Take a look at the pdf, it should guide you through the process

Comment: Will do! I'll tackle this tonight. Plus I'm buying your book!

Comment: Almost there. I got the old nested collection to clear out. I put the 
    slides.reset(slides) 
in the callback() and it's replacing with the new nested collection. Thanks again. I'll post the code once it is fully working.